# Does Proofwiki correctly state the intermediate value theorem?

Tags: calculus

This is how Proofwiki states the intermediate value theoem:

"Let $I$ be a real interval. Let $a,b \in I$ such that $(a..b)$ is an open interval. Let $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real function which is continuous on $(a..b)$. Let $k \in \mathbb{R}$ lie between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. That is, either $f(a)<k<f(b)$ or $f(b)<k<f(a)$. Then $\exists c \in (a..b)$ such that $f(c) = k$."

Shouldn't this suppose continuity on the closed interval $[a,b]$? Otherwise consider $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\arcsin(x)  & \text{-1<x<1} \\
23 & \text{if x=1} \\
-23 & \text{if x= 
-1}
\end{cases}$$

where $a=-1$ and $b=1$.

Here is the link: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intermediate_Value_Theorem

Comment: You could also use a much simpler $f$ as a counter-example. Let $f(x)=0$ in $(-1,1)$ and $f(-1)=-1, f(1)=1$. The $\arcsin$ in your example might make people misunderstand the nature of the counterexample, wondering what about that function in particular...

Comment: Older versions (2008) said "continuous on $I$," which makes sense - there is no reason to even include $I$ in the statement, really, as stated.

Comment: Specifically, the edit: https://proofwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Intermediate_Value_Theorem&diff=9145&oldid=8592

Comment: The statement at ProofWiki is now fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I agree.  The given statement is incorrect and your counterexample shows it.

An even simpler example might just be
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0, & x = -1 \\ 2, & -1 < x < 1 \\ 1, & x=1\end{cases}$$
with $k = \frac{1}{2}$.